# Login issue for this web site

Tags: forum

one of my friend has login for this forum but he was out of town for long time and did not access this forum for a long time and that is why he forgot his userid which he use to login to this web site. probably he use yahoo or gmail accound to login to this web site but now he could not remind his user id by which he login to this web site. so anyone can tell me how he can know what user id or mail id he used to login to this web site. how to request moderator of this web site to retrieve his login details.....at least his login id.

my friend profile is https://stackoverflow.com/users/750398/keith-costa   looking for help. thanks

Comment: Please post this question on [StackOverflow Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: I would recommend sending an email directly to [so] via the [contact us](http://stackoverflow.com/contact) page. I'm not sure that the *users* of the site will be able to help much with restoring an account.

Comment: @JonathanMee - better to take this directly to the [se] team. I don't think the community will be able to help much with regard to a users login credentials.

Comment: @Lix You've obviously been around a lot longer than I have, but I believe that the moderators also have access to this. Generally the best way to communicate with them is via http://meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: @JonathanMee - it's true that the mods can see a users email address...but in this case there is the need for some verification - no mod is just going to supply someone claiming to be this users friend with a users private email address... For this reason I would suggest going directly to the source :P to [se].

Comment: @Lix In this case I think that providing the mail site may be very useful, but obviously not the mail address.

Answer (score 1):

This is the [List of Moderators](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) at Stack Overflow. Only Moderators can see a user's email address. Try sending one of them a message with his user-id (750398), or contacting StackOverflow directly via [Contact Us](https://stackoverflow.com/contact).

That user Keith Costa (750398) hasn't logged in since Jun 20 2012, so I would also recommend he checks all of his email accounts for mail from around that time.

Good luck!